# What is the command in cmd for providing html documentation for predefined classes of java using javadoc command

Tags: javadoc

Suppose I want to provide an HTML documentation for a predefined class of java, for example: 
documentation for `java.lang.String`  API using Javadoc command in cmd (as I use windows 7).

Can anyone please tell me the exact command for such documentation? 
I know the synopsis of Javadoc command but I am getting several errors.

Note: The location of my src and bin folder is 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

Comment: Which command do you run and which errors do you see?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131>javadoc java.lang.String
Loading source files for package java.lang.String...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package java.lang.String
Constructing Javadoc information...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package java.lang.String
javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
1 error
2 warnings

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131>

Comment: Secondly if i copy exact String api from src folder into my current working directory then i get this error